# Save API data into an array with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need help doing this. I want to save the user list from the API to an array (called "name"). How can I do this? I tried this forEach but can't make it work. Thanks!

Edit: I  wraped the function, still not working.

```
import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          info: null,
          name: []
        }
      },
      mounted () {
        axios
          .get('http://localhost:3000/api/users/', {mode: 'no-cors'})
          .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
          .then(() => info.data.forEach(element => {

          }))
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            this.errored = true
          })
          .finally(this.loading = false)

      }
    }
```

Comment: What doing wrong?

Comment: Are you accidentally accessing `info` too soon after your `mounted()` call? Meaning since you are using an async request whenever you try to use your `info` property it has to happen after the request is done, not when `mounted()` is done being called

Answer (score 1):

From the code above I'm assuming the data in `this.info` in correct. The problems I see in your code are:

1.

```
.then(response => (this.info = response.data))
.then(() => info.data.forEach(element => {

}))
```

`info` looks to be undefined. I assume this should be `this.info`.

```
.then(response => (this.info = response.data))
.then(() => this.info.data.forEach(element => {

}))
```

Or if you're using the arrow function syntax and returning an assignment expression, you can use

```
.then(response => (this.info = response.data))
.then(info => info.data.forEach(element => {

}))
```

Which I don't really recommend, since some linting rules disallow returning assignment expressions (for good reasons). To chain a promise that relies on this implicit language behavior can make code less easily understood.

2.

What `forEach` does matters. Vue's reactivity does not pick up certain assignment syntax, i.e. `this.name[i] = element`. You can use array methods like `push`, but I recommend you use functional programming operators, like `map` and `filter`:

```
.then(() => (this.name = this.info.data.map(element => {

})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `this` reference is not correct, because on callback methods is on another context, try it:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      info: null,
      name: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    var self = this
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/users/', {mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then(response => (self.info = response.data))
      .then(info.data.forEach(element => {

      });)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(this.loading = false)

  }
}
```

Comment: Since OP is using arrow functions the `this` inside the function is going to be using the same `this` reference as `mounted()` scope, as arrow functions do not have their own `this`

Comment: You is alright, but in some cases it's not happens like documentation.

Comment: It can't happen any other way, that is how the native js works. The only thing that can change the context is how mounted() itself is executed which still wouldn't change how arrow functions work in js, they still won't have their own `this`.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to encapsulate the callback into a function receiving the `info` variable,
try this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      info: null,
      name: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/users/', {mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then((response) => response.data.forEach(element => {

      }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(this.loading = false)

  }
}
```